# In How many ways we can find the location in Android...?

Tags: android

In how many ways we can find the current location of the user. Can we find the current                   location without using GPS?

Can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 1):

There are several location providers available. *I think apps are even able to add their own provider?*

However, I think the [Network Provider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#NETWORK_PROVIDER) is what you're looking for:

> This provider determines location based on availability of cell tower and WiFi access points.

You will probably find more information [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html).

Have fun

Tom